# Nginx index.php not a directory

Tags: nginx

I'm a beginner with Nginx
I have the below link working fine with apache

```
https://127.0.0.1/shop/sub-shop1/index.php/product1/property1
```

but for the same thing with nginx

```
failed (20: Not a directory)
```

what is the solution?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your case if the one where you really need a `PATH_INFO` being extracted from the URI and passed to your backend PHP app. This is a really rare case nowadays, and while I keep seeing attempts to set that `PATH_INFO` FastCGI variable over and over again among various configurations such as

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    ...
}
```

it does not make any sense there because using that kind of PHP handler location no URI that really contains the `PATH_INFO` will be ever captured with the `\.php$` regex pattern. To make it workable use a proper regex pattern like the one suggested in the official [PHP FastCGI example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/):

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(?:$|/) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: still same error, what to have inside of the location block

Comment: In every other way it should be the same fastcgi handler as usual one. What PHP handler do you have in your nginx configuration right now? Maybe it will be better if you add your full nginx configuration to your question.