# nginx auth_basic on for the entire server, but off for a few URLs

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to enable **HTTP Basic Authentication** for all URLs except a few, but no matter what I try, I either get auth for all non-static URLs or no auth for all.

My config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dev.website.com *.dev.website.com;

        return 301 https://dev.website.com;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php-controller.conf;

        server_name dev.website.com;
        root /var/www/website/web/;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/localcerts/website/dev/website.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localcerts/website/dev/website.key;

        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/website/web/.htpasswd;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access!";

        location /just_a_simple.html {
                try_files /static$uri =404;
        }
        location / {
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
        }
        location /static {
                try_files $uri =404;
        }
        location ~ ^/en/(url1|url2) {
                auth_basic off;
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
        }
}
```

I'm trying to:

1. have the just_a_simple.html file served as static, unprotected and it works
2. have everything in /static served as static, unprotected and it works
3. have /en/url1 and /en/url2 passed off to FPM, interpreted as PHP, unprotected and it doesn't work, it's protected
4. have all other URLs passed off to FPM, interpreted as PHP, protected and it works

How can I make point 3 above work and achieve all 4 requirements?

> snippets/fastcgi-php-controller.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: It's as if **auth_basic off;** is entirely ignored in `location ~ ^/en/(url1|url2) {`. I read somewhere that it's because of "phases" and that nginx sees `rewrite ^ /index.php;` and never even considers `auth_basic off`

Comment: It would be nice to have some kind of feedback, either negative or positive, on the answer I give you.

Comment: Feedback is guaranteed, just need to find some time to disable the app's PHP auth and enable nginx's with your answer and test properly. I appreciate your comprehensive answer.

Comment: Ok, Meanwhile re-reading the answer I figure out that the first provided option actually can be applied to your config after all (see the answer edit history).

Answer (score 2):

You are right about request processing phases (described in the [development guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases)). Your `rewrite` directive will be executed at the `NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE` while `basic_auth` one register its handler at the later `NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE`. If you'd need to do an opposite thing, protect the `/en/url1` and `/en/url2` URIs leaving all the others unprotected, you'd have an option to use a `try_files` directive to jump to the PHP handler location at the even more later `NGX_HTTP_PRECONTENT_PHASE`:

```
location ~ ^/en/(url1|url2) {
    auth_basic "Restricted Access!";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/website/web/.htpasswd;
    try_files "" /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

However this is not an option for your particular case. What you can do instead is to rely on the [`$request_uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) built-in nginx variable, which is always contains an original non-normalized request URI and does not get changed during internal URI rewrites (in is the normalized [`$uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) one that does). Usually you have at least two options:

- use an `if` block to conditionally set the `auth_basic` directive parameter:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    set $realm "Restricted Access!";
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/en/(url1|url2)) {
        set $realm off;
    }
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/website/web/.htpasswd;
    ...
}
```

However since you have a customized `try_files` directive inside your PHP handler location, it won't be an option here since `try_files` [does not get inherited](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/86#comment:4) into the virtual nested locations created by `if` directive when used in the `location` context. Do you remember that [`if` is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)? So we should either move the `$realm` variable evaluation one level up to the `server` context (thus being executed at the `NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE`):

```
set $realm "Restricted Access!";
if ($request_uri ~ ^/en/(url1|url2)) {
    set $realm off;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/website/web/.htpasswd;
    ...
}
```

or better go straight to the second option:

- use a `map` block to evaluate the `auth_basic` directive parameter:

```
map $request_uri $realm {
    ~^/en/(url1|url2)  off;
    default            "Restricted Access!";
}
server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        auth_basic $realm;
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/website/web/.htpasswd;
        ...
    }
}
```

The second option will be somewhat more optimal since the `$realm` variable will be evaluated only when it needs to be.

---

P.S. Dealing with `PATH_INFO` inside your PHP handler makes no sense; you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72358252/7121513) why is it.

P.P.S. Did I mention you don't need that `location ~ ^/en/(url1|url2) { ... }` location in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to the location blocks you want to allow?

```
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
```

For example:

```
        location /just_a_simple.html {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all; # Allow all to see content
                try_files /static$uri =404;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it's one of the many things I tried and it doesn't work. Although, your example is about the static file, which works without auth_basic or allow all - it's unprotected, as intended. My problem is with `location ~ ^/en/(url1|url2) {`